# Why am I getting error while installing opencv on Raspberrypi3

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, virtualenv, raspberry-pi3

As I said I'm getting error while installing Open cv on Raspberry pi3 I'm following instruction from pyimagesearch. I get error as follow

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 72kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1
Successfully installed pip-9.0.3
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python3 get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1
Successfully installed pip-9.0.3
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-15.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.6MB 47kB/s 
Collecting virtualenvwrapper
  Downloading virtualenvwrapper-4.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting stevedore (from virtualenvwrapper)
  Downloading stevedore-1.28.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting virtualenv-clone (from virtualenvwrapper)
  Downloading virtualenv_clone-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
  Downloading pbr-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 278kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Installing collected packages: virtualenv, pbr, stevedore, virtualenv-clone, virtualenvwrapper
Successfully installed pbr-4.0.2 stevedore-1.28.0 virtualenv-15.2.0 virtualenv-clone-0.3.0 virtualenvwrapper-4.8.2
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/pip
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo -e "\n# virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper" >> ~/.profile
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo "export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs" >> ~/.profile
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.profile
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ source ~/.profile
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mkvirtualenv cv -p python2
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mkvirtualenv cv -p python3
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python3
Not overwriting existing python script /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python (you must use /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python3)
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ source ~/.profile
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
I get error as virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. How can I fix this error? I can't figure out why am I getting this error. I searched google It didn't fix my issue.I keep getting bash: /usr/local/bin/python3: No such file or directory
```

virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
 How can I fix this ? I tried to uninstall and reinstalling virtualenv it didn't workout.Do I need to reinstall software and begin from the start? Which takes a lot of time especially in raspberrypi I don't want to do this, help me to fix this problem

Comment: @api55 thanks for editing, do u know how to fix this?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, I think it may not have been installed to the correct python somehow...  you installed pip in python3, normally already pip should be installed when you installed python... the thing is that after that, you installed using pip, which could be maybe pointing to python 2 or any other python installation and then the script `uses /usr/bin/python`... which python is this one? python2, python3, any other one?... my suggestion is to make sure `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` points to either python2 or 3 where you want it to be installed...

Comment: Also you can use pip2 and pip3 to make sure it use pip of python 2 or 3

Comment: /usr/bin/python3